# JTree: how to check if current node is a file

Tags: java, swing, file, directory, jtree

I am using the following code to populate a JTree which is working perfectly

```
File [] children = new File(directory).listFiles(); // list all the files in the directory
for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { // loop through each
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(children[i].getName());
    // only display the node if it isn't a folder, and if this is a recursive call
    if (children[i].isDirectory() && recursive) {
        parent.add(node); // add as a child node
        listAllFiles(children[i].getPath(), node, recursive); // call again for the subdirectory
    } else if (!children[i].isDirectory()){ // otherwise, if it isn't a directory
        parent.add(node); // add it as a node and do nothing else
    }
}
```

Give a directory string, it adds all the files in that directory to the JTree, my problem is that i am unable to get the file from each of the nodes... i know you can use

```
jtree.getLastSelectedPathComponent()
```

to get the last selected component but what i really what is to check if the selected component is of type `File` and if it is, return the path of that file... does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The `DefaultMutableTreeNode` you are using contains a 'userObject', which in your case is the `String` representing the name:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(children[i].getName());
```

If you would store the `File` in the node (or any unique identifier for a `File`) you can retrieve it using the [available getter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#getUserObject%28%29).

If you opt for this approach, you will probably have to change the renderer on the tree. A renderer with equivalent behavior can be implemented by extending the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` and overriding the `getTreeCellRendererComponent` as follows

```
@Override
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus){
  Component result = super.getTreeCellRendererComponent( tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus );
  if ( value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode && ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)value).getUserObject() instanceof File ){
     ((JLabel)result).setText( (File)((DefaultMutableTreeNode)value).getUserObject()).getName() );
  }
}
```

Note: the code above is not tested. I hope I did not made any mistakes in my brackets, ... (too lazy to fire up my IDE)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small snippet looking more or less like yours (it would have been easier if you could have provided an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)). Basically, I changed the user object associated with the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` from a `String` to a `File`. I also added a customized `TreeCellRenderer` to only display the name of the `File` (and not its absolute path), and a `TreeSelectionListener` that outputs to the console the current selected `File` object.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;

public class TestTreeFile {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTreeFile.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTree tree = new JTree(createTreeModel(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")), true));
        tree.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
                    boolean hasFocus) {
                super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
                if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
                    if (node.getUserObject() instanceof File) {
                        setText(((File) node.getUserObject()).getName());
                    }
                }
                return this;
            }
        });
        tree.getSelectionModel().addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                Object object = tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                if (object instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
                    Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) object).getUserObject();
                    if (userObject instanceof File) {
                        File file = (File) userObject;
                        System.err.println("Selected file" + file.getAbsolutePath() + " Is directory? " + file.isDirectory());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setSize(400, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode createTreeModel(File file, boolean recursive) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file);
        if (file.isDirectory() && recursive) {
            File[] children = file.listFiles(); // list all the files in the directory
            if (children != null) {
                for (File f : children) { // loop through each
                    node.add(createTreeModel(f, recursive));
                }
            }
        }
        return node;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTreeFile().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You may also want to take a look at this [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

Comment: +1 (both) sorry (stupid hint) I miss there Colection.sort() for great code

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like this:

```
private boolean isFileSelected()
{
    TreePath treePath = tree.getSelectionPath();
    Object lastPathComponent = treePath.getLastPathComponent();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) lastPathComponent;

    return node.getUserObject() instanceof MyNodeObject;
}
```

`MyNodeObject` should be different from the folder data types so you can identify if the node is a file or not.